# Connect phone to computer?

Tags: android

In order to test out my game, I need to use my real life device. The problem is, android studio isn't recognizing my device plugged in:

**The problem:** My device isn't getting detected in android studio

**The solution:** Install the correct usb drivers

**The problem that arises to the solution:** I am not able to...and here are the details:

I have recently system wiped my computer due to slowness. This brings me back to the tedious task of setting up my computer for android studio. I have tried **everything** to get  the usb drivers to work in android studio, but for some reason, I can't update my usb driver:
[image]

Now, here is the annoying screen that always pops up when trying to update my usb driver:

[image]

My usb driver **is installed:**

[image]

This is pretty pathetic. I have tried everything. **I even tried to go into my computers bios and disable Intel xHCI.** I remember when I first started android, I had this same problem, and the solution was to do something in the computer's bios, but the problem still persists.

By the way, I have done lots of research on this topic, and this is a code 28, which means it doesn't have the correct drivers:

[image]

I have been on this for 3 hours now (3 HOURS!) and would really appreciate **any** help. How can I get my phone recognized on my windows 8 laptop? I have done it before, so I know my phone is compatible. Is there something I need to do in the bios? Virtualization is already enabled in bios.

I would really appreciate any help, and you all have my upvote.

Thanks so much,

Ruchir

Comment: Why are you showing a folder with the driver files? Did you try right clicking the "android_winusb" file and selecting "Install"?

Comment: @congusbongus Okay, I just did the install. What should I do now?

Comment: @congusbongus Thanks so much for your response, but it is still not working. What else can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is really the right question for this site. But I still personally uninstalled and reinstalled my Android Driver to install it again. It's not in English but all buttons should be placed the same. Make sure you have the right driver for your devices. Some might require special drivers.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Select show all units.
[image]
[image]

Make sure you select the right driver. Click browse and navigate to where on your computer the driver is saved. The driver should end in .inf, android_winusb.inf is this case.
[image]
[image]

Select show all units.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't say the question  really fits GDSE, but +1 to this answer for being thorough with screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have virtualization on in the bios.

Next, make sure you have done what I have done in my question.

What I forgot to do was install the `android_winusb` file in the usb_driver folder. The path should be `sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`. In my case, `C:\Users\Ruchir\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

After doing that, go **back** to device manager and go to the install as path. At the bottom of that should be another option:

Let me pick from a list of devices on my computer

Select your android phone, it shouldn't have a yellow exclamation mark over it any more. After that, select `composite ADB Interface`.

THAT'S IT.